# When does network spinner appear?

Tags: ios

Just out of curiosity what kind of network activity causes the spinner in the status bar to spin? It never spins in my app even when data is being fetched. In Instagram, it always spins when data is being fetched.

[image]

[image]

**Edit**: To clarify that this question is not a duplicate. I am wondering what makes the loading indicator appear in the status bar, not just how to make it appear. Is it common to call UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true every time a call is made to the server?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true` And set `false` when you want to hide it.

Comment: What API are you using for network call? Are you using NSURL or NSURLSession methods? Or some third party libraries?

Comment: Third party API

Comment: If you are using some third party library like curl you won't see activity indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Swift 2.0

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```

for Swift 3.0

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can show network indicator every time you make a call to web service.
You can show network indicator with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

and remove it when you received response from web service with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```